# sql many-to-many query result only if matches only and exactly all items in array

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have three tables on a mysql database:

```
| pieces   | line_up       | instrument    | 
--------------------------------------------
| id_piece | piece_id      | id_instrument |
| title    | instrument_id | instrument    |
```

now what I'm trying to achieve is: I'd like to query those pieces whose line_up is made up by exactly the instruments given by a list, not one less not one more.
This sql query reduces the result to those piece who are only played by the 2 instruments, but it includes the solos

```sql
SELECT id_piece, title FROM pieces WHERE
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM line_up WHERE line_up.piece_id = pieces.id_piece)
   =
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM line_up
   INNER JOIN instruments ON instruments.id_instrument = line_up.instrument_id
   WHERE line_up.piece_id = pieces.id_piece
   AND instruments.instrument IN ('guitar', 'drums'));
```

For example with these tables:

```
| pieces               |  | line_up                  |  | instruments                |
-----------------------   ---------------------------   ------------------------------
| id_piece | title     |  | piece_id | instrument_id |  | id_instrument | instrument |
-----------------------  ----------------------------   ------------------------------
| 1        | hello     |  | 1        | 1             |  | 1             | guitar     |
| 2        | goodbye   |  | 1        | 2             |  | 2             | drums      |  
| 3        | goodnight |  | 2        | 1             |  ------------------------------
------------------------  | 3        | 2             |
                          ----------------------------
```

the only actual piece for both guitar and drums, hence the result of my query, should be `1 | hello`.
Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use aggregation like so:

```
select p.id_piece, p.title
from pieces as p
inner join line_up as l on l.piece_id = p.id_piece
inner join instruments as i on l.instrument_id = i.id_instrument
group by p.id_piece
having sum(i.instrument in ('guitar', 'drums')) = 2
   and sum(i.instrument not in ('guitar', 'drums')) = 0
```

If you don't have too many instruments to search for, an alternative is string aggregation in the `having` clause:

```
having group_concat(i.instrument order by i.instrument) = 'drums,guitar'
```

This second expression requires that you give the query an alphabetically-ordered list of instruments.

Comment: There should be something that counts the number of requested items in place of 2

Comment: @astentx: well if that list of values is built in an application, you would expect the application to know how many values are given.

Comment: @GMB ..and that's exactly the case. Thank you very very much!

Comment: how many instruments would be 'too many'? I'm considering a max value of 30 instruments

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of rows that were filtered with instruments and compare it with the total number of instruments and number of instruments you've selected.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6fb438651fa33f8a00822fc14f965dc1)

```
with pieces as (
  select 1 as id_piece, 'hello' as title union all
  select 2 as id_piece, 'goodbye' union all
  select 3 as id_piece, 'goodnight'
)
, line_up as (
  select 1 as piece_id, 1 as instrument_id union all
  select 1 as piece_id, 2 as instrument_id union all
  select 2 as piece_id, 1 as instrument_id union all
  select 3 as piece_id, 2 as instrument_id
)
, instruments as (
  select 1 as id_instrument, 'guitar' as instrument union all
  select 2 as id_instrument, 'drums' as instrument
)
select p.id_piece, p.title
from pieces as p
  join line_up as l
    on l.piece_id = p.id_piece
  join instruments as i
    on l.instrument_id = i.id_instrument
group by p.id_piece, p.title
having sum(case when i.instrument in ('guitar', 'drums') then 1 else 0 end) = count(1)
and count(1) = (
  /*To select only valid instruments*/
  select count(1)
  from instruments as f
  where f.instrument in ('guitar', 'drums')
)

-----------+--------
| id_piece | title |
|----------+-------|
|        1 | hello |
-----------+--------
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Match by instrument combination.

```
SELECT title 
FROM pieces
WHERE id_piece IN (  
  SELECT piece_id
  FROM line_up 
  WHERE instrument_id IN (
    SELECT id_instrument
    FROM instruments 
    WHERE instrument IN ('Guitar', 'Drums')
  )
  GROUP BY piece_id
  HAVING group_concat(instrument_id order by instrument_id separator ',') = (
    SELECT group_concat(id_instrument order by id_instrument separator ',')
    FROM instruments
    WHERE instrument IN ('Guitar', 'Drums')
   )
);
```